# Failure of mlab.normpdf to produce a Gaussian fit

Tags: python, histogram, gaussian

Very new user, so apologies if I have done any of this wrong (also sorry for the links and not embedded images, I don't have enough reputation to embed an image).
Basically, I am intending to produce a Gaussian fit of a CSV file from my oscilloscope output using Python (specifically, `pyplot.hist` and `mlab.normpdf`), and measure its full-width-at-half-maximum. I've ran into several problems with this, most of which I have solved except for this one I cannot for the life of me solve.

My code reads in from the CSV file(s) and uses `pyplot.hist` to produce a histogram for it. Now, all of the data (except the first one, but this fails because i didn't collect the data correctly) produces a graph that looks distinctly Gaussian except for small bins that are on the outskirts of the histograms. I expected to solve this problem by using the `range` keyword to only have `hist` add up the data points in the part that looks Gaussian (might be bad practice, but this is necessary due to the method I have to do to get the system that the oscilloscope is hooked up to properly configured).

At first I thought this would solve my problem nicely. However, as I adjust the ranges to the segments that are important, `hist` still produces plots that have these small outlying bins that make `normpdf` produce unsatisfactory Gaussians.

For reference, here's a link to an image of a histogram (with overlaid Gaussian from `normpdf`) of one of my CSV files without using `range` in the argument of `hist` (using `bins='auto'`):
https://nofile.io/f/gM760eEoGsb/hist_norange.PNG (A stretched out gaussian fit over the entire length of the data, including an outlier far out)

I'm not sure if I'm correct, but I would posit that if it weren't for that tiny bin on the far right (and maybe some slight adjustment to ignore the far left of the histogram), `mlab.normpdf` should produce a reasonable Gaussian.

However, if I do include the `range` keyword, and use `range=(-0.95,-0.64)`, I get this instead: https://nofile.io/f/2UYcHY4P1E6/hist_range1.png (basically the same stretched out Gaussian but over a smaller range this time -even though I've restricted the range to the Gaussian-esque area)

And, for posterity, a histogram and fit if I restrict the range even further, to `(-0.83,-0.74)`: https://nofile.io/f/tpmvgF1ydYj/hist_range2.PNG

The actual Gaussian doesn't change shape at all, it just compresses the ends of it to the arguments of the tuple I pass to `range`.

At this point I have no idea what's causing this, whether it's a fault with my code, a fault deeper in `hist` or `normpdf` or a fault with the data I've taken (which I originally thought, but after optimising the system to the best of my ability I'm leaning heavily towards ruling the third option out).

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

data = np.empty([1203])
z = ['NewFile1.csv', 'NewFile2.csv', 'NewFile3.csv', 'NewFile4.csv', 'NewFile5.csv']
ranges = [(-0.85,-0.53), (-0.85,-0.79), (-0.8,-0.7), (-0.83,-0.71), (-0.74,-0.65)]
q = 0
for x in z:
    print('Accessing file', x)
    with open(x) as csvfile:
        offset = -2.0E-3
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        i = 0
        for row in reader:
            data[i] = row['CH1']
            data[i] = (data[i])/pkpk
            i = i + 1

    plt.figure()
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data,bins='auto',normed=1,facecolor='blue',range=ranges[q])
    avg = np.mean(bins)
    sd = np.sqrt(np.var(bins))
    plt.plot(bins,mlab.normpdf(bins,avg,sd))
    plt.show()
    q = q + 1
```